# python matplotlib plotly graph_objects how to save a figure

Tags: python, plotly

How can I locally save the graphics which is produced like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig2 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=xData, y=yData, marker_color='lightblue'))
fig2.update_layout(title_text=title)
fig2.update_layout(width=900, height=350)
fig2.update_yaxes(showticklabels=True,range=(0, 350))
fig2.show()
```

Under other circumstances in the same jupyter notebook.
`fig.savefig('filename')`  works well. But here fig2 is lacking this method.
As a newcomer all those different methods to produce graphics in the python environment are driving me crazy. Appreciate any help.

Comment: To save it as an image, you need to add a library as shown below.
`pip install psutil requests`.
[Static Image Export in Python](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/)

Comment: Thank you. Yet another library to import.

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?